# How to make all controls read-only based on a rule?

Tags: .net

I have a .aspx page with many controls such as Form View, Grid View etc.

Based on a rule which we capture on a database table, I would like to make this page read-only. The edit button, update button in the gridview, formview and simple textbox should be made read-only.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: All contols have a property called [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.enabled.aspx).

Comment: True. But I don't want to add it for all controls, as I have many.

Comment: Setting Enabled = false on a container control (panel, user control, web form, etc) is meant to disable all of it's children as well.

Comment: Use container controls like Panel and put related contols into it, then you could disable that control. If any parent control is disabled, all child controls are disabled implicitely.

Comment: Thanks Tim. It worked. But it looks grayed out. Is there a way to change the graying out?

Comment: @user728148 - it's a bad idea to disable cotrols, but remove the feedback that they're disabled (graying them out).  Otherwise, people will be confused why things don't work.

Comment: @user728148: It is user-friendly to let them know that they cannot change anything. If you anyway want to let the controls look `enabled`, you could use CSS.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Do you have an example how to set CSS through code-behind?

Comment: That isn't that simple. Every control is rendered as a different element-type in html(possibly different on different bowsers). So even if i would show you a way how to do it for an input element(f.e. `type="Text"`), the same css might not work for a `select` or `button` or in Firefox or.. or..or. I wouldn't invest much time to confuse users. maybe your disabled-approach is not the right way. Why do you want to disable the whole page?

Comment: Thanks Tim.By disabling,did you mean by making the page inaccessible? I cannot do that, as they might want to view the page at a later stage when they shouldn't have edit access to it. I am disabling the whole page by using the Panel.Enabled=False. Is there any other way to disable the page?

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying I don't know ASP.  If I were using a WinForm, however...

You can set `Enabled = false` on the Form or a Panel to automatically disable all child controls.

```
Form.Enabled = false;
// or
MyDataPanel.Enabled = false;
```

Or you can create an array of all controls requiring attention and itterate through that.

```
private MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Control array must be initialized after InitializeComponent is called.
    dataControls = {
        EditButton,
        UpdateButton,
        FormView,
        SimpleTextBox};
}
private readonly Control[] dataControls;

private void BulkSetEnabled(bool value)
{
    foreach (Control control in dataControls)
        control.Enabled = value;
}
```

**EDIT:** In response to comments in the question.

Some controls have a `ReadOnly` property which, when set, prevent changes to the data and present the content with better readability.  But something like a Button won't have this, so now you have a combination of controls, some requring `Enabled = false` and other requiring `ReadOnly = true`.  Two arrays and two loops can do that.

Comment: Thanks Hand-E-Food. I cannot use ReadOnly property for data controls, as they don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="MyPanel" >
    Name:
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NameTextBox" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Phone:
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PhoneTextBox" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Code (when not editable):

```
MyPanel.Enabled = false;
```

Code (when editable):

```
MyPanel.Enabled = true;
```